# Не получается сохранить код. sublime text 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, sublime-text-3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хочу сохранить код. Build system - javascript есть. В чем ошибка? Местоположение проверял, вроде все правильно.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте задать новую рабочую папку в саблайме.